# PHP class attribute not persisting data of Eloquent join query after constructor

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel job class and I'm initializing a Collection attribute with an Eloquent join query. Inside the constructor everything works fine.

The problem comes in the handle method of the class, that specific attribute losses the value initalized previously in the constructor. With a simple Eloquent query everything works well, the value persists.

Here's how the constructor looks like and the model class where the Eloquent join query is made:

```
class CreateResponseFile extends Job
{

     /**
     * @var Collection
     */
     protected Collection $records;

     public function __construct(ResponseWriter $parser, $body)
     {
        $responseID = $body["response_id"];
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->response = Response::where('id', $responseID)->firstOrFail();
        if($parser instanceof WriterCsv){
            $this->records = ResponseRecord::getConciliatedRecords($this->response);
        }else{
            $this->records = ResponseRecord::where('response_id', $responseID)->get();
        }
        $this->file = $body["path"];
    }

}


class ResponseRecord extends Model
{
    public static function getConciliatedRecords(Response $response)
    {
        $records = self::where("response_id", $response->id)
                    ->join("conciliated_trxs", function($join){
                        $join->on("response_records.id", "=", "conciliated_trxs.response_trx_id");
                    })
                    ->join("presentation_records", function($join){
                        $join->on("presentation_records.id", "=", "conciliated_trxs.presentation_trx_id");
                    })
                    ->get();
        return $records;
    }
}
```

Comment: so the `records` property has no value in the `handle` method? does your Job use the `SerializesModels` trait?

Comment: @lagbox That's correct, the `records` property has no value in the `handle` method using a join query to initialize, but using a regular query it works fine. And yes, I see that the Job class is using the `SerializeModels` trait.

Comment: it should be a collection no matter what since `get` is called, regardless of the join ... so that is interesting